# how to prove $\frac {(a_1+...+a_k-1)!}{a_1!...a_k!} \in \Bbb N$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

if $a_1,...,a_k  \in \Bbb N$ , $\gcd(a_1,...,a_k)=1$ how to prove:

$$\frac {(a_1+...+a_k-1)!}{a_1!...a_k!} \in \Bbb N$$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Observe that this is reminiscent of the [multinomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_coefficient):

$$\binom{a_1+\ldots+a_k -1}{a_1, \ldots, a_i-1, \ldots, a_k}$$

for each $i, 1 \le i \le k$; we know all of those are integers.

The quantity $\dfrac{(a_1+\ldots+a_k-1)!}{a_1! \cdots a_k!}$ results from them by dividing by $a_i$. So for each $i$:

$$a_i \dfrac{(a_1+\ldots+a_k-1)!}{a_1! \cdots a_k!}$$

is an integer. Can you take it from here?

Comment: how to use from $\gcd(a_1,...,a_k)=1$ also we must product this statement to $a_i!$ how to use to prove  the statement for example: $2 . \frac{r}{2q} \in \Bbb N, $but we have :$ \frac r {2q} \not \in  \Bbb N$

Comment: Indeed, you have to use [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_identity#Generalizations) as well.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\gcd(a_1,...,a_k)=1$ we have:

$$x_1a_1+...+x_ka_k=1 \tag{I}$$

Let $ A=\dfrac{(a_1+...+a_k-1)!}{a_1!...a_k!}$ we have by $I$:

$$Ax_1a_1+...+Ax_ka_k= A \tag{II}$$

Also we know that $a_iA \in \Bbb N$ because $a_iA = \binom{a_1+\ldots+a_k -1}{a_1, \ldots, a_i-1, \ldots, a_k}$, 
thus $x_ia_iA \in \Bbb N$ so by $II$ we have $A \in \Bbb N$.

Comment: Nice to see you managed to work it out!